# How to remove bad sectors from SSD disk, format, create partitions and install win 10

Tags: ssd, gpt, bad-sectors, fixmbr

Upgraded my disk to a new SSD but seem to have screwed it by not realising that my Dell desktop Vostro was only a MBR bios and I tried to create a GPT system partition. Now after many and varied attempts to fix running through the gamuts of DiskPart, Easeus, Aoemi and Disk Genius, I have a 953gb disk showing in DiskPart and initialised with no Partitions that doesn't appear with List Volume. Neither can I Clean it, Create a Partition, format it or do anything! Whatever I do brings the same message..."A device which does not exist was specified". I've now acquired a Lenovo M82 G1 that has both MBR and GPT capabilities and just want to install Win10 and a few Linux Distros and sleep again.......many thanks for any help, Tony

Comment: Try creating a bootable USB for FDISK and delete all partitions on the SSD.  Then you should be able to format it.   https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-create-a-bootable-usb-fdisk

Comment: `WinKey`+`R` → `DiskPart` → `lis dis` → `sel dis #` → `clean` _(if needing to configure it with GPT: `convert gpt`)_. If the drive is being used on UEFI motherboard, GPT should be used _(it's not a partition, it's a partition table)_ and CSM [Legacy] Mode in the UEFI firmware should be disabled prior to doing so.